# Can ESLint "--fix" no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs automatically?

Tags: eslint

I am running lint and getting "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs". Is there a way to have the `--fix` flag just substitute the tab with n spaces?

Comment: There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6873) but it seems like it was never implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Answering directly: as of January 2024, no, `no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs` cannot be fixed automatically.

You can check whether any built-in ESLint rule has a *fixer* (which will fix automatically) or *suggestions* (which have to be triggered automatically) by visiting [eslint.org/docs/latest/rules](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules). The rule's entry on that page will indicate whether it has a *fixer* and/or *suggestions*.

You can also visit the rule's dedicated docs page. [eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs) is the docs page for `no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs`. The docs page will mention if there's a *fixer* and/or *suggestions* for the rule.

---

Separately: since this question was asked, the built-in `no-mixed-spaces-tabs` rule was deprecated and moved to the [ESLint Stylistic](https://eslint.style) project. You can read more about that on https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/17522 -> https://eslint.style/guide/why.